# android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

i got some problem in my code .I try to use android studio to create a app that can let user log in , but when i run my php file , it just show **{"success":false}** in a webpage .Next , in the android studio logcat alsoshow some error and my app crash . What is the wrong?

error in Login.php:

**{"success":false}**

error in app:

**FATAL EXCEPTION: main**

**Process: com.example.user.loginregister, PID: 2304**

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference**

Login.php file:

```
  <?php
$con = new mysqli("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password =?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $name, $username, $password);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;

}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

LoginRequest.java

```
   public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest{
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://finalproject.16mb.com/android/Login.php" ;
private Map<String , String> params;

public LoginRequest( String username ,String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

LoginActivity.java

```
 public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    final TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);

    registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

           Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success){
                            String name= jsonResponse.getString("name");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("name", name);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);

                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);


                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            };

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly one of your `EditText` fields are not initialized via the `findViewById(R.id.some_editText_id);` can you please check the layout file or post the same for more info.